# Authorization for laravel passport through websocket

Tags: laravel-5, websocket, laravel-passport, laravel-echo

I have a private channel. And i can use it only if i authenticated on site. But in case of laravel passport i have no idea how it should be work. By default all what i need contains in cookies.
What i have:

```
Broadcast::routes();
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

`Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api']]);` have no effect.

How do I authenticate users through laravel passport, for that would be connected to a private channel websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the current moment the echo does not support authorization with the help of laravel passport, it is necessary to write your own sokket.io server.

Answer (score 4):

I been through this, and my solution was using Laravel Echo & Laravel Echo Server for SocketIo.

Retrieve the user access token, then store it in cookie or application storage, and inject it while you instantiating or re-instantiating Laravel Echo, like the following:

```
let Echo = require('laravel-echo')

window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
        auth: {
            headers: {
                 Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AUTH_API_TOKEN,
            },
        },
    });
```

References:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites
2. https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server